# Trying to create a form in docusign with some conditional formulas

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to create a form in DocuSign with some conditional formulas. I need a field to show a deposit amount that is formulated based upon criteria.

> If the total of a project is >=$X than Deposit amount =Project total/3,

> or if the project total <= $X than Deposit Amount  = Project Total/2

```
IF(ProjectValue >= 10000, ProjectValue / 3, 0)
IF(ProjectValue <= 10000, ProjectValue / 2, 0)
```

Got a Formula Error. Portions of this formula are not valid:

```
IF(ProjectValue &gt;= 10000, ProjectValue / 3, 0)
```

Comment: Are you building an integration, using APIs, are you a developer writing code? Or are you just trying to use DocuSign features from the web app?

Comment: I am using the web app. I have a document that I am trying to make into a template, that I can edit as needed. I need the template to show a $deposit amount based on the $Project Value. Either a 1/3, deposit amount, or a 1/2, deposit amount, based upon dollar amount.

Comment: So this (Stackoverflow) is for developers. I suggest you ask in community.docusign.com